# deploy django webserver on apache

Tags: django, apache, wsgi

I have tested my blog website using:

```
 python manage.py runserver
```

Everything is correct. Now I want to deploy my blog site on apache. But I cannot configure apache with django correctly. Basicly, my blog structure is the following:

```
├── blog
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── blog
│   │       ├── css
│   │       ├── images
│   │       └── js
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── blog
│   │       ├── base.html
│   │       ├── index.html
│   ├── templatetags
│   │   ├── custom_filter.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
├── blogC
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
└── usermanage
    ├── admin.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py
```

I have installed the apache, mod_wsgi and database. My question is the django middleware will look for static files automatically. Should I add the path to the static files in the httpd.conf? How should I write the configure file? I follow the instruction on django official website. But it turned out the apache service cannot restart, so I must configure it wrong.

Update the last several lines of the error.log:

```
[Tue Feb 10 10:02:08.796042 2015] [core:error] [pid 6610] (13)Permission denied: [client 113.240.234.213:14433] AH00035: access to /phppath/php5 denied (filesystem path '/home/ec2-user') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
[Tue Feb 10 10:02:11.700382 2015] [core:error] [pid 5220] (13)Permission denied: [client 113.240.234.213:15162] AH00035: access to /local-bin/php denied (filesystem path '/home/ec2-user') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
[Tue Feb 10 10:02:12.407788 2015] [core:error] [pid 5257] (13)Permission denied: [client 113.240.234.213:15339] AH00035: access to /local-bin/php5 denied (filesystem path '/home/ec2-user') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
[Tue Feb 10 10:02:13.118587 2015] [core:error] [pid 5221] (13)Permission denied: [client 113.240.234.213:15501] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/ec2-user') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
[Tue Feb 10 11:14:12.291824 2015] [core:error] [pid 5218] (13)Permission denied: [client 205.145.18.5:47369] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/ec2-user') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
[Tue Feb 10 11:14:14.319037 2015] [core:error] [pid 6308] (13)Permission denied: [client 205.145.18.5:57326] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/ec2-user') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

Comment: I used "apache:www" as user/group in the httpd.conf file. And I changed the   owner of contents in the static folder to be apache. But I got the permission denied when using http access from browser.

Comment: I searched the log file. It said: "search permissions are missing on a component of the path". Since I use apache:www in configure file. But the django folder is in my ec2-user account. So I replaced apache:www as ec2-user:ec2-user. But I still get the same error.

Comment: Which OS are you using. Apache user and group usually `www-data:www-data`. Moreover, you normally don't want to change a user, which apache runs as. Any particular reason why you setting a user and group manually?

Comment: I used the redhat OS.  The default user and group are apache:apache in this case. And I got the error something like that "You don't have permission to /home/ec2-user for some search path". That's the reason I changed the the user:group, since all the django codes are located in /home/ec2-user folder.

Comment: Gotcha. You still don't need to change the user, just make sure you project code is readable by all: `chmod -R a+rX  /home/ec2-user/path/to/project`

Comment: I have already changed the permission as "755" for all the folders. But I still got the same error, which is very weird. The error log keep saying I don't have permission....

Comment: It has to be a file permission issue, but I've never really had an issue like that. Only thing I can recommend is make sure each folder on the path to project is executable for all, including the root folder `/`. Otherwise I am out of ideas, and without looking at your config files and file permissions I don't think I'll be much of help.

Comment: I got it! It turned out to be the selinux problem. I thought I was using enforcing mode and gave permission to apache. Today, I disabled the selinux, and the permission problem went away.

Comment: Awesome. Glad you where able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible apache config:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess blog processes=2 threads=15
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/project/blog/blogC/wsgi.py

<Directory /path/to/project/>
            WSGIProcessGroup blog
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            Options All
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /media/ /path/to/project/media/
<Directory /path/to/project/media/>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /static/ /path/to/project/static/
<Directory /path/to/project/static/>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Also create a `static` and `media` folders in your projects root folder and set them in `settings.py`:

```
import os

BASE_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Then collect all static files into provided directory (this will link static files from all apps into one location):

```
./manage.py collectstatic --link
```

Also make sure apache has permissions to write into media folder, so files can be uploaded:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/project/media
```

Now you gotta make sure your `wsgi.py` is configured correctly:

```
import os, sys

## apache/mod_wsgi cannot find the path without it!
path = os.path.split(os.path.dirname(__file__))[0]
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "blogC.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

That should be it.

Comment: I found the reason that why httpd service didn't restart. I removed the <VirtualHost> tag for above configuration(I don't know why at this moment). But I have a new problem when I try to browse the website. I got the messege: "you don't have permission to access / on this server"

Comment: Can you post the actual error trace back from apache log file `/var/log/apache/...error.log`